# Adding items from list to listbox control

Tags: c#, list, listbox

Had a scout around, but can't find anything that works.

I have a list of an undetermined size, and I'm trying to display it in a list box `List<String> urls`

Items are dynamically added to the list by doing `urls.Items.Add(string)`

I've tried doing `lstURLS.Items.Add(urls)`, and it returns `Collections` in the list box.

I've also tried `lsturls.Datasource = urls` but it doesn't recognise that as being valid code.

Is there an easy method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a for each loop:

```
for each (string s in urls) {lstUrls.Items.Add(s);}
```

I think this is what you're looking for?

Comment: @JordanMoffat to add the list at once w/o a foreach, use `AddRange(urls)`